# Finding JavaScript functions inside a file via regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, annotations

does anybody no of a libraray or search pattern to find a complete (or at least the end) of a JavaScript function?

I am parsing JS-Files to gather annotation and other information, but couldn't find a regex that finds JS functions (the though part are the parentheses, I guess).

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

The minimum RegEx to search for this might be:

```
(function\s*([\s\S]*)\s*\{[\s\S]*\})+?
```

but there is no guarantee that this will find everything properly. Also, what happens if there are functions within functions? You'd need some sort of parser rather than using RegEx.